# Reshape image to [-1, 1] with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, reshape, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to reshape images in `[0, 255]` to `[-1, 1]` using `ImageDataGenerator`?

I have seen that I can multiply the image with a value using the reshape parameter, but that only gives me the possibility to reshape it to `[0, 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the preprocessing_function in Keras ImageDataGenerator class.

> **preprocessing_function**: function that will be applied on each input. The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape.

```
#preprocessing_function function
def changeRange(image):

   image[:, :, 0] = [(i/128.0)-1 for i in image[:, :, 0]]
   image[:, :, 1] = [(i/128.0)-1 for i in image[:, :, 1]]
   image[:, :, 2] = [(i/128.0)-1 for i in image[:, :, 2]]

   return image

#data augementation
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
   rescale = None,
   preprocessing_function=changeRange)
```

`

Comment: I believe the function could be expressed as `return [(i/128.0)-1 for i in image[:, :, :]]`

Comment: Yes, this may be even better =)